# Semicircle function that returns 0 for all values that aren't on the circumference

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

I am looking for a function y=f(x) that creates a semicircle (radius 1) that also returns 0 (rather than being undefined) for x values that are not on the circumference of the semicircle,

I'm not sure if this is possible as  semicircle functions that I am aware of such as

$$\sin(\cos^{-1}(x))$$

and

$$\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Are undefined outside of the circle because they use trigonometric inverse functions or square root

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You could just use a piecewise function

Comment: One possibility is $\sqrt{\max\{0,1-x^2\}}$, although a piecewise function is probably better communication to the reader.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to define such function in Mathematics is
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-x^2} & \text{ if }|x|\le 1\\
0& \text{ if } |x|>1 
\end{cases}
$$
It's a common mistake from beginners to try to construct a "single expression formula" for such kind of functions, which almost always obscure the definition and make it more impractical to work with.